# How can we read avro events sent from flume?

Tags: java, flume, avro

I want to read avro events being sent through flume and update a user cache . Is there a java client already present to read avro events from a port and host? And what is the fail-safe way of doing so? I mean how is that java code supposed to handle a failure either in Flume or what if the tcp queue becomes full?

Comment: hi mohit_d! did you find some way to solve this issue ?

Comment: @mohit_d, buddy, did you solve that?